# How do I disable a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

Somehow I have managed to create some sort of keyboard shortcut so that when I press the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key capital I and hit space, it defaults to Is.

How can I disable this function?

Comment: What app does this happen in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right click on the desktop shortcut of the application
>
> Select "Properties"
>
> Select the Shortcut tabs,
>
> Remove the Keyboard shortcut

Comment: So it was an auto-correct problem, not a shortcut.  Problem solved anyway.  thanks.